# MySQL query finding if not_exists

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, exists

I've two tables in order: 'sat' and 'clientes'

- `sat`

  - `status`
  - `id`
  - `tecnico`
  - `clientid`
  - `fecha`
  - `incidencia`
  - `trabajo_realizad`
  - `fecha_trabajo`
- `clientes`

  - `id`
  - `cliente`
  - `phone`
  - `address`

I want to do a query (I'm using PHP). The tables:

- sat: by unique 'id' I am adding in other page "tickets" (opening tickes for assistance). When one of my clients have problemas I open a ticket with unique id.
- 'fecha_trabajo' is a date field in which I insert the date when I'm going to visit that client.
- clients: one client, one id. This id is for the client, its not the same id as in the 'sat' table.

Well, they are relationated by this fields: clientes.id = sat.clientid.

Ok.. I print all the tickets and their information (sat.id,sat.incidencia...) and I print clientes information of all the sat.id (tickets) that 'sat.trabajo_realizado' (done) are not done.

But now, I want to know what clients I have visited by month. For example, I want to print clientes.cliente (name of the client) of all clientes.cliente that haven't any sat.id (ticket correspondant) this month.

I have tried with this but it doesn't work. First, MONTH function seems to doesn't work.

```
$informacion_pte = conexion("SELECT sat.status, clientes.id, clientes.cliente, clientes.direccion, clientes.telefono FROM sat INNER JOIN clientes ON sat.clientid = clientes.id WHERE NOT IN
        (SELECT clientes.cliente from sat INNER JOIN clientes ON sat.clientid = clientes.id WHERE MONTH(NOW())=MONTH(fecha_trabajo) and year(now())=year(fecha_trabajo) GROUP BY clientes.id)
        GROUP by clientes.cliente");
```

Comment: A very small point about English.  "Wanna" isn't a proper English word.  It is a verbal contraction of "want to", and "want to" should be used in writing.

Answer (score 0):

This WHERE clause does nothing: `WHERE MONTH(NOW())=2 and year(now())=2015`
It is `true` for *all* rows since `now()` is February 2015.

You probably wanted to compare `MONTH(now())` against a database column.

Comment: ok sorry, its MONTH(NOW())=MONTH(fecha_trabajo and the same for YEAR.